# cannot get url data using GET request

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, url, get

hi I am trying to use GET to send some json data.
I tried using this way 
`This is the url = localhost/index.php/getRequest?name=BestRate&secret=masnadsapi`

```
public function getRequest(){
        $verb = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($verb == 'GET'){
            if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($GET['secret']) ){
               $name = $_GET['name'];
               $secret = $GET['secret'];

               if($name == 'BestRate' && $secret == 'masnadsapi'){
                   $foo = array(
                       'Todays Best Rate' => '5.6%'
                   );
                   $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
                    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($foo));
               }else{
                   return;
               }

            }else{
                echo 'Masnad says  : no parameter giving' ;
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is Message: Undefined variable: GET
For the secret part.

Comment: Change `$GET['secret']` to `$_GET['secret']` (in both places you are using it).

Comment: Oh thanks!!! I did not notice that at all!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Please write a answer so I can accept it !
Thanks alot

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of literal mistakes. You need to relook at your code and change `$GET` to `$_GET`.

For example here:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$secret = $GET['secret'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `$GET['secret']` to `$_GET['secret']` (in both places you are using it)